# Html design issue on small screens , Twitter Bootstrap Custom Login

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, login-page

My main problem is about the login page template i've copied, any idea how to fix it ?

I adjusted the width of the box because its too wide for my project. I added certain width set the modal-dialog to its width 450px .`modal-dialog { width:450px; }` .Its ok now in the browser but why is it that when i view it on small devices like for example iphone4 it is not responsive now?

```
    <div id="loginModal" class="modal show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h1 class="text-center">Login</h1>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<form class="form col-md-12 center-block">
<div class="form-group">
<form method="POST" action="login.php">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Username">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Sign In</button>
<span class="pull-right"><a href="#">Register</a></span><span><a href="#">Need help?</a></span>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<div class="col-md-12">
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
</div>  
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please rewrite your question, it's very unpleasant to read...

Comment: please help me regarding this im new to bootstrap

Comment: provide a working example here, or on jsfiddle, and point out what you exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

Well as you said you've set your modal-dialog to be:

```
.modal-dialog { width:450px; }
```

That's not responsive, that's fixed - you need to add other widths to your modal dialog within the media queries blocks of bootstrap

E.g:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.modal-dialog { width: 300px; }
}
```

Note the code above is for example and not the exact code you need as you'll nede to figure out what is best for your project.